# How to assign unused special keys on keyboard to a macro?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, macros

I have an old "compaq internet keyboard" pictured below. Many of the top keys no longer work in windows 10 without the correct software, or do something completely unrelated (for example: eject opens vlc).

My interest is not to make these keys do what they are supposed to. My interest is to repurpose these keys to do something useful. For example, a couple buttons could open different applications, another one could be dedicated to showing task view, another 2 for copy/paste, etc. Is there any way to accomplish this?

[image]

Comment: OS? What have you tried already? What were the results?

Comment: OS is windows 10. not sure where to start. I would argue it is not a duplicate because that person was talking about standard keys. I have weird unique keys that may not be recognized by most applications

Answer (score 0):

There are a number to utilities that can do what you ask. I would recommend AutoHotkey. Most of those extra keys have documented functions which can be remapped. For the rest you may need to do some work to find the keycodes generated and then you can map them as you want.

Here is a list of known special keys on my installed copy AutoHotKey,

```
Browser_Back Back 
Browser_Forward Forward 
Browser_Refresh Refresh 
Browser_Stop Stop 
Browser_Search Search 
Browser_Favorites Favorites 
Browser_Home Homepage 
Volume_Mute Mute the volume 
Volume_Down Lower the volume 
Volume_Up Increase the volume 
Media_Next Next Track 
Media_Prev Previous Track 
Media_Stop Stop 
Media_Play_Pause Play/Pause 
Launch_Mail Launch default e-mail program 
Launch_Media Launch default media player 
Launch_App1 Launch My Computer 
Launch_App2 Launch Calculator
```

For the rest, you can use the command `#UseHook on` in the script file to then be able to see the key codes generated by pressing the special buttons.

https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/64875-mapping-special-keys/ for a related discussion and information. More here, https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/64503-make-the-fn-key-usable/